# Angular 5 - Typescript: json2typescript cant run the package

Tags: angular5

I've installed it using npm, followed the github readme but I cant seem to load the package and get the functionality running.

This is one of my classes using the package.

```
import { JsonObject, JsonProperty } from 'json2typescript';

@JsonObject('AssignmentOrganizationalUnitReference')
export class AssignmentOrganizationalUnitReference extends ReferenceBase {

@JsonProperty('OrganizationName', String)
OrganizationName: string = undefined;

@JsonProperty('Name', String)
Name: string = undefined;

@JsonProperty('Active', Boolean)
Active: Boolean = undefined;

@JsonProperty('IncludeSubUnits', Boolean)
IncludeSubUnits: Boolean = undefined;

@JsonProperty('AssignmentRoles', [AssignmentRole])
AssignmentRoles: AssignmentRole[] = undefined;

@JsonProperty('UnitId', String)
UnitId: string = undefined;

@JsonProperty('Type', OrganizationalUnitReferenceType)
Type: OrganizationalUnitReferenceType = undefined;
}
```

This is my systemjs

```
(function (global) {
System.config({
    defaultJSExtensions: true,
    paths: {
        // paths serve as alias
        'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
        // our app is within the app folder
        'app': 'app',

        // angular bundles
        '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
        '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
        '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
        '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
        '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
        '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
        '@angular/common/http': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common-http.umd.js',

        // other libraries
        'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
        'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
        'tslib': 'npm:tslib/tslib.js',
        'ngx-infinite-scroll': 'npm:ngx-infinite-scroll/bundles/ngx-infinite-scroll.umd.js',
        'ngx-spinner': 'npm:ngx-spinner/ngx-spinner.umd.js',
        'jquery': 'Content/platform/scripts/extensions/jquery-1.7.2.js',
        'json2typescript': 'npm:json2typescript/index.js'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
        app: {
            main: 'app/main.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js',
            meta: {
                './*.js': {
                    loader: 'systemjs-angular-loader.js'
                }
            }
        },
        rxjs: {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    }
});
})(this);
```

I get an error when I load the page. Its looking for the files representing what I am importing but cannot find them. It gives me 404s..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding this to 'packages' in systemjs.config.js: 
            json2typescript: {
                defaultExtension: 'js',
                main: 'index.js'
            }